# I'm creating a ModelBinder. What do I do to change the way it binds the property from the model back to the client on EditorFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I've learned how to create a custom ModelBinder that successfully changes the way the properties are set as parameters of my controller actions.

Now how do I intervene the inverse way? changing the way it sets the property back from the model to the View in the `EditorFor` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Default Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html).

This is basically a snippet of code that is used for the type. It needs to be in the `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates` and `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`.

Name of the view needs to be name of the Class.
This way you may change `DateTime` and other basic types as well.

Comment: well, that makes a lot o sense. Actually the other way around is solved with templates, not with ModelBinders. That worked. Thanks so much